# How to save the value entered by the user in the calculated field?

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo, odoo-15

I made the computed field editable using the inverse field, but when I entering the value manually, when saving it is replaced with the value from _compute_test, how can I save the value entered manually?

My .py file:

```py
class SaleOrderInherited(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'sale.order' 

    custom_field = fields.Char(string='Test',
    compute="_compute_test", inverse="_inverse_compute_test")

    #warning = fields.Boolean(default=False)

    @api.depends('tax_totals_json', 'date_order')
    def _compute_test(self):
        for record in self:
            if int(json.loads(record.tax_totals_json)['amount_total']) == 0:
                record.custom_field = randint(1, 1000)
            else:
                record.custom_field = f"{json.loads(record.tax_totals_json)['amount_total']} - {record.date_order}"

    def _inverse_compute_test(self):
        pass
```

My .xml file:

```xml
<odoo>
  <data>
<!--Inherit the sale order form view--> 
        <record id="view_sale_order_custom" model="ir.ui.view"> 
            <field name="name">sale.order.custom.form.inherited</field>
            <field name="model">sale.order</field> 
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="sale.view_order_form"/> 
            <field name="arch" type="xml"> 
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='partner_id']" position="after"> 
                    <field name="custom_field"/>
                </xpath> 
            </field> 
        </record>
  </data>
</odoo>
```

I tried using force_save, but it doesn't help, and I didn't find another way.

Answer (score 0):

Use `store=True` attribute in your field.

You also need to enforce your compute method logic so it doesn't always override field's value.

`force_save` attribute is used for read-only fields, which would be ignored from  `create` and `write` methods instead.

Comment: Thanks. How i can enforce my compute method logic so it doesnt override field value?

Comment: Depends on your needs. For sure you should not always override field value, but only in certain conditions. For example, you could update value only in certain cases (maybe if value is null, or calling compute method only when other fields changes), but as i said depends on your needs